# How to fix Dell 2408WFP LCD making high pitch noise?

Tags: display, lcd, repair

I have two Dell 2408WFP LCD monitors that I purchased new a bit over 2 years ago. One of them suddenly started making a fairly loud high pitch noise after turning it on. As well there was a noticeable electronic smell of some sort. It still displays perfectly fine though, no flickering and it's still as bright as the other. I've of course unplugged it for now. What do you think might be wrong and how can I fix it?

Asking around it sounds like the backlight inverter might be going bad. If that's the case I'd be interested in any details about replacing it. I've found it available [here](http://www.lcdrepair.us/2408wfp-inverter.html) for $49.99. My other concern is that my other monitor might soon need this same repair since they were purchased at the same time. Or was I just unlucky with the one hitting its MTFB early? I have several other Dell LCD monitors that go back almost 10 years now and haven't had a problem with those.

Thanks for any help or insight you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your warranty! The 2408WFP was released in 2008 with a 3 year warranty from Dell, so you might still be covered. Call 1-800-915-3355 to get it replaced under warranty. Just enter zeros for the express service code since the monitor doesn't have one.

Comment: They're shipping me a replacement in 1 to 2 business days. I just have to ship the bad monitor back in the same box.

Comment: Well. Not that I have problem with self-answering question and self-assigning answer... But this is not supposed to be done this way...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the LCDs just go. A squeal sounds to me like a failing capacitor, though it could be any number of other problems.

In my experience, 90% of LCD repairs are categorized as Backlight or FL Inverter issues. If you can find the replacement and feel competent replacing it, have at it. I've never actually performed this repair, and as most monitors are not made to be easilty dissasembled, you'll probably need a bit of glue or zip ties to hold it together once you're done.

But hey, glue and zip ties for a $50 repair for a 24" LCD monitor? I'd live with it just fine.